# How to get FileName and Directory of Windows Control Panels?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, control-panel

In Delphi, create a VCL Forms Application. Use the 64-bit Windows platform if you are on a 64-bit Windows.

Use the following code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  CodeSiteLogging,
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure GetControlPanelItems;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Winapi.ShlObj, Winapi.ShellAPI, System.Win.ComObj;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetControlPanelItems;
end;

procedure TForm1.GetControlPanelItems;
var
  psfDeskTop: IShellFolder;
  psfControl: IShellFolder;
  pidControl: PITEMIDLIST;
  pidChild: PITEMIDLIST;
  pidAbsolute: PItemIdList;
  pEnumList: IEnumIDList;
  celtFetched: ULONG;
  FileInfo: SHFILEINFOW;
  ShExeInfo: SHELLEXECUTEINFO;
begin
  OleCheck(SHGetDesktopFolder(psfDeskTop));
  OleCheck(SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(0, CSIDL_CONTROLS, pidControl));
  OleCheck(psfDeskTop.BindToObject(pidControl, nil, IID_IShellFolder, psfControl));
  OleCheck(psfControl.EnumObjects(0, SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS or SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN or SHCONTF_FOLDERS, pEnumList));

  while pEnumList.Next(1, pidChild, celtFetched) = 0 do
  begin
    pidAbsolute := ILCombine(pidControl, pidChild);
    SHGetFileInfo(LPCTSTR(pidAbsolute), 0, FileInfo, SizeOf(FileInfo), SHGFI_PIDL or SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME or SHGFI_TYPENAME);

    CodeSite.Send('TForm1.GetControlPanelItems: szDisplayName', FileInfo.szDisplayName);

    // Exe-Info:
    ZeroMemory(@ShExeInfo, SizeOf(ShExeInfo));
    ShExeInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(ShExeInfo);
    ShExeInfo.lpVerb := 'Open';
    // control panel item's PIDL:
    ShExeInfo.lpIDList := pidAbsolute;
    ShExeInfo.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    ShExeInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_IDLIST;
    //ShExeInfo.lpFile := ???
    //ShExeInfo.lpDirectory := ???

    CodeSite.Send('TForm1.GetControlPanelItems: ShExeInfo.lpFile', ShExeInfo.lpFile);
    CodeSite.Send('TForm1.GetControlPanelItems: ShExeInfo.lpDirectory', ShExeInfo.lpDirectory);
  end;
end;

end.
```

This gets me the **Display names** of the control panels.

But how can I get the file-paths? (ShExeInfo.lpDirectory, ShExeInfo.lpFile)

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. Not all of the Control Panel items are executables. Many are run using `rundll32.exe` and are not directly executable stand-alone.

Comment: In addition, one executable could also contain more than one control panel applet.

Comment: What us the underlying problem.  You aren't interested in knowing their names I guess. You want to invoke them perhaps?

Comment: I need to create shell link shortcuts (.LNK) to the control panel applets. So when I double-click the shortcut (.LNK) the control panel applet is opened. But I need the names too, of course, for that I use FileInfo.szDisplayName. And David, please stop downvoting my questions!

Comment: You know the `ITEMIDLIST`, so set it up to your created link (`IShellLink`) by the `SetIDList` method.

Comment: P.S. for getting display name one might use `SHGetNameFromIDList` function. And ask proper `HRESULT` constant in your loop (or use e.g. `Succeeded` function).

Comment: There aren't necessarily files names for each applet. So what you ask for can't be achieved.

Comment: There are 5 downvotes. Not even I have that much power. I was responding to your comment where you insist on having filenames. I guess you now realise that you were mistaken in that regard.

Comment: If you think your item identifiers are files, you can use SHGetPathFromIDList.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned here, it might be worthless to try getting file name of a certain applet binary as there can be more than one applet implemented in a single binary. For your overall task, dropped in your comment, creating shell shortcut links, simply use absolute [**ITEMIDLIST**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773321(v=vs.85).aspx) that you know in your loop, and set it to the created [**IShellLink**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774950(v=vs.85).aspx) object by the [**SetIDList**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761050(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment, please? That is a correct approach. Even MSDN explains the `SetIDList` like _"This method is useful when an application needs to **set a Shell link to an object that is not a file, such as a Control Panel application**, a printer, or another computer."_